# RSpec test failing looking for a new set of eyes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Here my issue:

I've got two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :username

  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
end
```

with this simple routes.rb file

```
TestProj::Application.routes.draw do |map|

 resources :users do
  resources :tasks
 end
end
```

this schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20100525021007) do

  create_table "tasks", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "estimated_time"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
 end

 create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
   t.string   "email"
   t.string   "password"
   t.string   "password_confirmation"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.string   "username"
 end

 add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
 add_index "users", ["username"], :name => "index_users_on_username", :unique => true

end
```

and this controller for my tasks:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_user

  def new
    @task = @user.tasks.new
  end

  private

  def load_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

end
```

Finally here is my test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe TasksController do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    @task = Factory(:task)
  end

  #GET New
  describe "GET New" do

   before(:each) do
      User.stub!(:find).with(@user.id.to_s).and_return(@user)
      @user.stub_chain(:tasks, :new).and_return(@task)
   end

   it "should return a new Task" do
      @user.tasks.should_receive(:new).and_return(@task)
      get :new, :user_id => @user.id
   end
 end
end
```

This test fails with the following output:

```
1) TasksController GET New should return a new Task
Failure/Error: get :new, :user_id => @user.id
undefined method `abstract_class?' for Object:Class
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:1234:in `class_of_active_record_descendant'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:900:in `base_class'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:655:in `reset_table_name'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:647:in `table_name'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:932:in `arel_table'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:927:in `unscoped'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb:30:in `scoped'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:405:in `find'
# ./app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:15:in `load_user'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:431:in `_run__1954900289__process_action__943997142__callbacks'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `send'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:8:in `process_action'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:113:in `process'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:39:in `sass_old_process'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/gems/haml-3.0.0.beta.3/lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:26:in `process'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/testing.rb:12:in `process_with_new_base_test'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:390:in `process'
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:328:in `get'
# ./spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb:20
# /home/chopper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@rails3/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:209:in `inject'
```

Can anybody help me understand what's going on here?  It seems to be an RSpec problem since the controller action actually works, but I could be wrong.

Comment: What does `Factory` do? Everything here looks fine. What if you don't use `Factory`, but create the user by hand for the test? Do you have YAML fixtures being loaded somewhere? I've only ever seen this error when I discovered I was calling a protected method in a fixture.

Comment: Factory 
is the main method of Factory_Girl, but even I I just use Active Record to create the @user object and the @task object nothing changes.

Comment: I have a similar problem and dont have a clue, did you fix it? I end up stubing the find method but you did the same and it doesnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your project from scratch using the information you supplied, and the controller spec runs without any failures (Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7). So I'm guessing there's something amiss in your project and/or Rails configuration? Sorry, I know that isn't much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this error message with my Rails 3 app using rspec-rails 2.0.0.beta22 (under Ruby 1.9.2). After lots of hair pulling I upgraded to the recently releases rspec-rails 2.0.0.rc and the error disappeared. So, I'd recommend upgrading your rspec-rails gem.